# How to send data back and navigate to a specific screen? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

I have a calendar widget which selects a date in the form of `DateTime`. I want to send this value using `Navigator.pop` but i also want to use a `MaterialPageRoute` which sends the user back to a page. I cannot use `Navigator.pop` this way :

```
   onPressed: () async{
              DateTime send = date;
              Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DayPageViewExample(date),
             )
         );
   },
```

because the user will be navigating to the calendar screen in this flow : initial screen => second screen => calendar screen. and the selected date in the calendar must be sent back to the initial screen.

I essentially want something like this:

```
 onPressed: () async{
      DateTime send = date;
      Navigator.pop(context, send);
    },
```

but i want to send the `DateTime send` as a parameter to `MaterialPageRoute`.

Could i get some suggestion on how to refactor the `Navigator.pop` so that i can send a parameter back using `MaterialPageRoute`?

Comment: you want to use `pop()` method to push a new `MaterialPageRoute` on the navigator stack? it makes a little sense for me - what do you need that `MaterialPageRoute` for?

Comment: i need to use the page route to send the user to the initial page, but in the final version of this application, the user will be navigating to the calendar screen using another page in the middle. When i use ```Navigator.pop``` it i can either send the user back to the second page with the ```DateTime``` from the calendar OR it can use the Page Route to send the user to the initial page without the ```DateTime```. I have tried to use ```Navigator.push``` but that recreates a new duplicate initial screen instead of popping back to the original initial screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue: TabScreen -> TakePhotoScreen -> DisplayPhotoScreen and after the photo was displayed, I wanted to return to the TabScreen with a specific tab selected.

In DisplayScreen I wrapped the main widget with `WillPopScope`:

```
body: Center(
    child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _handleNavigatorPop,
        child: ...
    )
)
```

`_handleNavigatorPop` method shows an alert dialog. On "Yes" action:

```
actions: <Widget>[
    FlatButton(
        child: Text("Yes"),
        onPressed: () async {
            final PageRouteBuilder _route = PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
                return TabsScreen(tabIndex: tabIndex);
            });

            //to remove all the routes below the pushed route, use a RoutePredicate that always returns false (e.g. (Route<dynamic> route) => false).
            await Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, _route, (Route<dynamic> r) => false);

            return Future.value(false);
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("No"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ]
```

Read more: [pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

Comment: I have modified this on my ```Flatbutton``` and it Pops perfectly. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

For return to first route you can use `popUntil` - like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

But if you want to send result - I think you can use `pushReplacement`

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DayPageViewExample(date),
         )
     );
```

It will just open new route with closing existing ones

Hope this is what you need

Comment: the issue with this method is, although it sends the ```DateTime``` to the initial screen, the push is recreating a duplicate initial screen; instead i want it to pop back to the original initial screen.

Comment: @HappyTurtle if you want to `"pop back to the original initial screen"` then simply use `pop()` with your `DateTime` passed as a parameter to `pop()`method or i am missing something obvious...

Comment: @pskink  since the navigation route is defined like this : initial screen => second screen => calendar screen. this method seems to be popping me to the second screen although i am able to send the ```DateTime```. In a nutshell, i need something like this : initial screen => second screen => calendar screen =>(using Navigator.pop and sending ```DateTime```) => initial screen

Comment: The main issue i am facing is, the ```Navigator.pop``` seems to allow me to send only two arguments: (context, value). For the value i am only able to send the ```DateTime``` or the ```MaterialPageRoute``` at a time. but i want to send both.

Comment: @HappyTurtle and no, this is not a main issue: your issue is that you want to make a "double pop" (going back from 3rd screen to 1st screen) and `popUntil()` does not take any result as a parameter (i have no idea why it was designed so...)

Comment: Is there any way i can perhaps reference the buildcontext of the initial screen and send that as the context argument in ```Navigator.pop```?

Comment: @HappyTurtle if you want to avoid `push` and only make double-`pop` with sending results - I see the only way. As pskink wrote - use `pop` with parameters. You just have to use it twice - to return to second screen and right after - to initial screen

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => DayPageViewExample(date)),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
);
```

This will remove all the routes below the pushed route.

[Read more about pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)